# running php5.3 in multiple php enviroment fails

Tags: php, apache

I'm working on a Ubtuntu System with PHP versions installed: 5.3.30 / 5.5.9 / 5.6.27 / 7.0.1

I'm able to switch between 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0 easily with a2enmod and a2dismod. But I am not able to run 5.3. I always get 5.5 instead. I followed following guides:

[first guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823252/installing-php-5-3-29-from-sources-on-ubuntu-14-with-apache-2-module)

[second guide](http://bernhardhaeussner.de/blog/89_Howto:_PHP5.3_parallel_zu_PHP5_installieren)

Then I tried to enable the 5.3 with a special vhost configuration and also with htaccess Addhandler directive. Nothing works. I think the reason is, that 5.3 has to be called in another way, but I've no idea anymore.

Comment: you should say "LoadModule php5_module /path/to/libphp5.so"  at your /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load, and not in vhost configuration and/or .htaccess

Comment: I did but with a2enmod php5 its loading php5.5 not php5.3

Comment: that means libphp5.so it points to is for php5.5. are you sure about you libphp5.3 location?

Comment: no. locate libphp5.3 gives me nothing....

Comment: that's exactly what it should give you. php5.3 module will be named libphp5.so as well. try to compile it with another prefix,  and put the full path  at  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load

Comment: compiled with --prefix=/usr/share/php53

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127110/discussion-between-sotona-and-falk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so guide #3 should look like:

- wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
- tar -jxvf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
- cd php-5.3.29
- ./configure --prefix=/path/to/custom/location **--with-apxs2** --with-WHATEVER-YOU-NEED --enable-WHATEVER-YOU-NEED
- make

after that libphp5.so along with all requested shared libs will be in /path/to/custom/location/**lib**,  which should be reflected in apache2 config.

just a sidenote: PHP 5.3 is too old, buggy and has lots of deprecated stuff so using it will bring a lot of pain

Comment: But sometimes you'll need it for old painful applications. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it runs now. There have been several problems.

1. Needed to install apache2-dev
2. symlink two files:

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.a /usr/libpcre.a && ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 /usr/libpcre.so

3. configure with option --with-apxs2

Then I installed it and it works perfect.

Great thanks to [sotona](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1520793) for helping me in chat with it.

Comment: actually step 2. is a dirty workaround, editing "configure" script would be more elegant