# php 5.3/mysql: why doesn't apache see mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm unfortunately having to install php 5.3.29, Apache and MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04, its proving to be much more difficult that I expected to get them working together.

I've tried folllowing [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823252/installing-php-5-3-29-from-sources-on-ubuntu-14-with-apache-2-module/29173314) and got php 5.3.29 installed.

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Jun 16 2020 04:00:04) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I got Apache installed:

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr  3 2019 18:04:25
```

Also got MySQL installed:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

It looks like these are all installed as expected but when I create a `phpinfo()` script and look at the page it correctly shows the version of `php` but has no details for `MySQL`.

When trying to access a page that uses `mysql` I get the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

It seems like `Apache` doesn't see `MySQL` for some reason but it does appear to be loading the module.

This is what I see when restarting apache:

`* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                         [Thu Jun 18 05:31:41.808127 2020] [so:warn] [pid 121446] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

**What do I need to do to get Apache to 'see' mysql?**

Comment: why would apache need to `see` mysql ?  you probably why does my php5.3 when called from apache not `see` mysql ?  look at the php.ini which apache uses. Different from the cli php.ini.

Comment: _“Also got MySQL installed:”_ - just because you got the MySQL database itself installed on your system, does not mean PHP automatically knows how to talk to it - you need to install / enable the PHP extension for that as well. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.setup.php

Comment: Show us the output of `phpinfo`

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the mysql extension is installed in php.

```
dpkg -l|grep php
```

then you should get a list of all php packages. Check if there is something with mysql / mysqli. If not you have to install the mysql / PDO package.

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

You use an extreme old PHP version which is not maintained anymore. So you should really upgrade and use a newer one. Then you should be able to connect with your php script to the database.

Comment: I tried that, got an error, tried php5-mysql and got this:  $ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded.

Comment: Then the package is installed and should be visible in your phpinfo. Normally the extensions are automatically enabled.

Comment: Yeah I know, I've installed LAMP loads of times and not had this problem.  This is all down to having to use an old version of php.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04, apache, mysql and php from scratch, not sure what the problem was but after reinstalling it seems to have resolved the problem.  I now have a new problem, so I might need post a new question,